# error login handling meteor

Tags: error-handling, meteor

I have this custom login form

```
<template name="login">
{{> alert}}
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="username" >
            <input type="password" name="password" >
        <input type="submit" value="Login" >
    </form>
</template>

<template name="alert">
    {{alert}}
</template>
```

I want to put error alert if user failed to login. this is the code to trigger alert message.

```
Template.login.events({
    'submit': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var usernameVal = event.target.username.value;
        var passwordVal = event.target.password.value;
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(usernameVal, passwordVal, function(err){
            if(err){
                Session.set('alert','login failed!');
                return false;
            }
            else{
                Session.set('alert',null);
            }
        });
    }
});

Template.alert.helpers({
    alert:function(){
        return Session.get('alert');
    }
});
```

The problem is when I trigger the error and try to open other page and back to login page, the alert message still there. Alert message only disappear when I refresh my browser or login successfully.

How is the best way to use error handling so the alert message only triggered once. This is including other forms error handling.

Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear the Session var when you come back to the view, like this:

```
Template.login.rendered = function () {
    Session.set('alert', null);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a timeout on your alerts. Define globally in a "app.js" file if you want this behavior for all your alerts. I got this in my meteor app. Your alerts will stay for 6 secs:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
if(Session.get('alert')){
    setTimeout(function () {
          Session.set('alert','');
      }, 6000);
    }
});
```